# C# Docker Container Error - dotnet/aspnet:6.0 - System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/.local/share/NuGet/Migrations' is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, docker, .net-core

I have started getting this error now which wasn't coming before in my .Net (ASP .Net 6.0) C# Docker Container.

Image Used: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-bullseye-slim`

Error:

```
10:50:23  + docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run --user=999 -e DOTNET_CLI_HOME=/tmp/dotnet_home -e DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1 unit-tests
10:50:23  Creating ci_unit-tests_run ... 
10:50:23  Creating ci_unit-tests_run ... done
10:50:24  System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/.local/share/NuGet/Migrations' is denied.
10:50:24   ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
10:50:24     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
10:50:24     at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath)
10:50:24     at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
10:50:24     at NuGet.Common.Migrations.MigrationRunner.GetMigrationsDirectory()
10:50:24     at NuGet.Common.Migrations.MigrationRunner.Run()
10:50:24     at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.DotnetFirstTimeUseConfigurer.Configure()
10:50:24     at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ConfigureDotNetForFirstTimeUse(IFirstTimeUseNoticeSentinel firstTimeUseNoticeSentinel, IAspNetCertificateSentinel aspNetCertificateSentinel, IFileSentinel toolPathSentinel, Boolean isDotnetBeingInvokedFromNativeInstaller, DotnetFirstRunConfiguration dotnetFirstRunConfiguration, IEnvironmentProvider environmentProvider, Dictionary`2 performanceMeasurements)
10:50:24     at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, TimeSpan startupTime, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
10:50:24     at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

Adding `XDG_DATA_HOME` as an environment variable and setting it to `/tmp/dotnet_home` just like I did for `DOTNET_CLI_HOME` fixed the issue.

New command is as follows:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run --user=999 -e DOTNET_CLI_HOME=/tmp/dotnet_home -e XDG_DATA_HOME=/tmp/dotnet_home -e DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1 unit-tests
```

Reference: [GitHub - dotnet/core - Issues - Interacting with NuGet fails on .NET 6.0.10 when running in docker with user](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7868)